# Tkinter - Crear ventana

Tags: python, tkinter

cómo andan? Recién empecé a utilizar el módulo Tkinter, pero desde el principio tengo un problema. Realicé una búsqueda por el foro y, si bien hay algunos temas sobre esto, ninguno parece solucionar el que tengo yo (salvo que no esté viendo bien).

Cuando quiero crear una ventana, me sale el error "**ImportError: cannot import name 'Tk' from partially initialized module 'tkinter' (most likely due to a circular import)**". El código que uso es:

```
from tkinter import Tk
 
ventana_principal = Tk()
 
ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

También intenté usar:

```
import tkinter
 
ventana_principal = tkinter.Tk()
 
ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

y el error que recibo es "**AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)**". Estos códigos son usados en videos introductorios en Youtube y a ellos les funciona perfectamente.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar el problema? Los códigos los saqué de dos videos distintos de Youtube.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: El código que publicas no provoca el error que mencionas, así que me temo que no estás incluyendo todo el código o hay algún problema con tu instalación de `tkinter`. ¿Te funciona con otros scripts o te da error en cualquiera que lo use?

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge c: De casualidad el nombre de tu script es "tkinter.py"?

Comment: Probé tus códigos en un script llamado "tkinter.py" y me dan los mismos errores que nos dices, así que creo que esa es la causa. Espero tu comentario. Y si me dices que así es, escribiré una respuesta explicando más a fondo lo que sucede. Recuerda que para que me de cuenta de tu respuesta, puedes notificarme escribiendo la palabra "@dantes." en tu comentario.

Comment: @jachguate Tengo una sospecha. Creo que el OP incluyó todo el código, pero el nombre de su script le causa problemas.

Comment: @dantes sisi. El nombre del script es ese. Te agradezco por tu respuesta y espero la explicación.

Comment: @dantes le cambié el nombre a ventana.py y ahora abre la ventana. De todas formas, si podes escribir la respuesta explicando el motivo, te lo voy a agradecer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Una breve introducción a como funciona la importacion de modulos en Python

Python, además de importar modulos, te permite importar otros archivos py.
Supongamos que tienes dos scripts en una misma carpeta:

**script1.py**

```
import script2
script2.hola_mundo()
```

**script2.py**

```
def hola_mundo():
    print("hola mundo")
```

En este código script1 importa a script2 que tiene la función hola_mundo y llama dicha función.

Como habrás notado, Python no solo te permite importar modulos, sino también otros scripts.

Recuerda que los modulos de Python también son scripts. Por lo que cuando haces `import modulo` o `from modulo import func1, func2, ...` en realidad Python primero busca en la carpeta donde está el programa un script que se llame igual que el modulo. Si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia en la carpeta de tu programa, busca en la carpeta "[ubicación de tu python]/lib"

## Explicación

Tu problema está en esta línea `from tkinter import Tk` en el primer código y aquí `import tkinter` en el caso del segundo código.

El objetivo de estas lineas es importar el modulo Tkinter de Python, que sería el que permite crear la ventana.

Debido a lo que expliqué en la sección anterior, tu script "tkinter.py" NO está importando el modulo Tkinter, si no que se está importando a si mismo. Es decir, tkinter.py importa a tkinter.py.

## Solución

Como haz visto, cambiarle el nombre al script a otro nombre es la solución. Por que? Por que por ejemplo si tu programa se llama "ventana.py" y no importas ningun modulo llamado ventana en el programa, entonces no ocurre este fenomeno de importarse a si mismo, ya que no estás importando nada que se llame como tu script.

---

Hice lo mejor que pude para explicarme, cualquier duda que tengas dime c:

Comment: Perfecto. Se entendió a la perfección. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que se entendiera nwn. De nada! Si mi respuesta te sirvió, puedes agradecermelo aceptando la respuesta c:

Comment: Aceptada. Pensé que con el voto era suficiente jeje

Comment: No te preocupes, lo entiendo! Te invito a leer esta pagina para saber que hacer cuando alguien responde tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Como dice el link, no te sientas presionado a aceptar la respuesta c:

Answer (score -1):

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gisel\OneDrive\Escritorio\Practica tkinter\color.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "c:\Users\gisel\OneDrive\Escritorio\Practica tkinter\tkinter.py", line 4, in <module>
    ventana= tk.Tk()                  #
             ^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'tk'?
```

Comment: si, pude solucionarlo no debe haber ningún archivo y/o carpeta con nombre tkinder