# Python no ejecuta Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, librería, python-3.9

Hola tengo un problema al ejecutar mi codigo en *pygame* el cual no me ejecuta el programa, pero al momento de escribir el código si lo detecta, me muestra el siguiente error:

***AtribuibleError: partially initialized 'pygame' has not attribute 'init' (most likely due to cicular import)***

He probado desinstalar *pygame* pero no funciona.

Cabe destacar que mi de nombre de proyecto le puse pygame.py

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Por favor el error ponlo como texto y muestra el código, no somos adivinos, no sabes que es lo que estás haciendo

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación y solución

Bienvenido Alexander! c:. Te pasó lo mismo que a este usuario: [Tkinter - Crear ventana](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446469/tkinter-crear-ventana/446568#446568)

Basándonos en la respuesta que le di a ese usuario, podemos deducir lo que sucede.

En alguna parte del código intentas importar el modulo pygame. Pero como tu script se llama pygame.py, tu juego intenta importarse a si mismo, NO al modulo Pygame. Es decir, pygame.py importa a pygame.py.

La solución de este problema sería que cambies el nombre de tu script a otro para evitar este "malentendido" de Python. Por ejemplo ponle de nombre al script "game.py".

Estoy un 75% seguro de esto. Lo deduje a partir de tu mensaje de error que dice el nombre del archivo en donde el error sucedió.

## Consejos sobre hacer preguntas en SO

Para tu proxima pregunta te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo minimo y verificable como ya te han dicho en los comentarios. Además, evita poner mensajes de error y código en forma de imagen. Por ejemplo puede que queramos probar tu código y no son muchas las personas que tienen el tiempo y la motivación para transcribir código en una imagen. Piensa que pasaría si nuestras respuestas estubieran en forma de imagen. No te gustaria, no?

El ejemplo minimo y verificable nos permitirá ayudarte con más facilidad.
Para darle formato al código, puedes seleccionarlo y apretar las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto donde editas/escribes tu pregunta.

En realidad, se supone que no debería responder preguntas que no cumplen lo esperado por la comunidad, pero decidí ayudarte de todas formas. No todos te ayudarán si ven que tu pregunta no cumple las expectativas de la comunidad. Además de que será mas difícil que te ayudemos.

Aquì te dejo (gracias al consejo de @christian) el enlace a como preguntar para más información. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Te falto darle el enlace a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muchas gracias, disculpa las molestias :)

Comment: No te preocupes, no me molestaste en lo absoluto c: Si mi respuesta te sirvió puedes aceptarla c: No te sientas presionado a ello.